# Redraw shapes in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to develop a painter app using MFC with C++.

So I set up a view in which I do the actual painting. However, when I open the color button I get "leftovers" of the menu on my canvas view.. I have no idea how to erase them.. I tried using `SaveDC` and `RestoreDC` to restore it to the previous state but no luck there. As I understand it is meant to restore properties of the device context such as pen & brush but it has no use for me...

I also need this feature so when I put up a rectangle, I could present a preview for it, but the "previews` are again presented like leftovers.

My view's `OnEraseBkgbd`;

```
BOOL CanvasView::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    if (!isBackgroundInit)
    {
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        CBrush myBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255)); // dialog background color
        CBrush* pOld = pDC->SelectObject(&myBrush);
        BOOL bRes = pDC->PatBlt(0, 0, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), PATCOPY);
        pDC->SelectObject(pOld); // restore old brush
        isBackgroundInit = true;
        return bRes;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My OnPaint:

```
void CanvasView::OnPaint()
{
    CDialogEx::OnPaint();
    //UpdateData(true);
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);
    if (dc == nullptr)
    {
        dc = new CClientDC(this);
        //dc->CreateCompatibleDC(dc);
        HDC hdc = CreateCompatibleDC(*dc);
        this->hdc = &hdc;
    } else 
    {

        BitBlt(*dc, 0, 0, (int)rect.Width(), (int)rect.Height(), *hdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    }
}
```

How it looked at first:

[image]

How it looks when opening a color button:

[image]

How it looks after closing the color button menu(leftovers marked with red arrows):

[image]

When trying to put up a rectangle:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this and really restore drawing?

Comment: Looks like your are not properly handling your view's `OnEraseBkgnd()` call/override.

Comment: @AdrianMole sorry, added my `OnEraseBkgnd` for my view

Comment: @AdrianMole I don't reset my background every time since I don't want the painting done to be erased as well.. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Yes. You need to store your image in a bitmap/memory-DC, then `BitBlt` that to the view's DC in the `OnDraw()` override. (And call `RedrawWindow()` when you exit the color-select pop-up.)

Comment: See the documentation provided by Microsoft, e.g. [Walkthrough: Updating the MFC Scribble Application (Part 1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/walkthrough-updating-the-mfc-scribble-application-part-1). Comes with *complete* source code.

Comment: @AdrianMole yeah, tried using the memory dc but probably did something wrong.. Added my `OnPaint`

Comment: Why are you using a `CClientDC` (as opposed to a `CPaintDC`)? Likewise, why are you calling the base class implementation? And why is the DC `new`d? Though some will disagree, no doubt, I will still suggest this: Postpone your MFC adventures until you have a firm grip on the Windows API. Petzold's [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X) is mandatory reading for *any* Windows developer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do.
`CView` has a virtual method called `OnDraw`. This is the method you must override:

```
void CMyView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
  CMyDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
  ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
  if (!pDoc)
    return;

  // first erase the entire client rectangle
  CRect cr;
  GetClientRect( &cr );
  pDC->FillSolidRect( cr, RGB( 255, 255, 255 ) );

  // your actual drawing goes here
  pDC->Rectangle( 0, 0, 100, 100 );
}
```

You will also have to write `OnEraseBkgnd`:

```
BOOL CMyView::OnEraseBkgnd( CDC* /*pDC*/ )
{
  return TRUE; // we fill the client rectangle in OnDraw
}
```

Also, it looks like you are trying to implement an ad-hoc memory DC. There is already one: [`CMemDC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/internal-classes?view=vs-2019).